# addClass doesn't apply

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
      $('nav').addClass('shrink');
      console.log(1);
    } else {
      $('nav').addClass('shrink');
      console.log(2)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.nav {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #555555;
  color: #000000;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
}

.shrink {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href=""> <img src="img/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="name"> <a href=""> YE AN EDUCATION </a> </div>
  <li> <a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code is executing fine, all the if statements are working. The problem is that styles are not applying and I can't figure out why. Even using "!important" doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target is incorrect..

`$('nav')` should be `$('.nav')`

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
            $('.nav').addClass('shrink');
            console.log(1);
        } else {
            $('.nav').addClass('shrink');
            console.log(2)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Rick points out the nav is incorrect - but so too is the else statement - it should remove the class on the else statement.

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
      $('.nav').addClass('shrink');
      console.log(1);
    } else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('shrink');
      console.log(2)
    }
  });
});
```

Incidentally - this can be done nicely with a ternary statement

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
       $(window).scrollTop() > 300 ? $('.nav').addClass('shrink') : $('.nav').removeClass('shrink');
  });
});
```